# I can't get the same results with these queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need convert this query from SQL Server 2008:

```
select distinct 
    i.art, i.des1, isnull(l.porc_tol, 0) as porc_tol, 
    0.0, a.cia, a.alm, 
    i.art, i.lin, i.s_lin, i.fam, i.s_fam, i.marca, a.cve_pro 
from
    invsas v (nolock), 
    invars s (nolock), 
    inviar i (nolock), 
    invart a (nolock), 
    invtol l (nolock) 
where
    v.cia = 'DEM' 
    and v.cve_suc = '001' 
    and s.cia = v.cia 
    and s.alm = v.alm 
    and s.sub_alm = v.cve 
    and i.art = s.cve_art
    and a.cia = s.cia 
    and a.alm = s.alm 
    and a.art = i.art 
    and l.cia =* s.cia 
    and l.suc =* v.cve_suc 
    and l.cve_art =* i.art
```

to SQL Server 2012. I made these changes:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    i.art, i.des1, ISNULL(l.porc_tol, 0) as porc_tol, 
    0.0, a.cia, a.alm, 
    i.art, i.lin, i.s_lin, i.fam, i.s_fam, i.marca, a.cve_pro 
FROM
    invart a (nolock),
    invtol l (nolock) 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    invars s ON l.cia = s.cia
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    invsas v on l.suc = v.cve_suc
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    inviar i on l.cve_art = i.art
WHERE
    v.cia = 'DEM' 
    AND v.cve_suc = '001' 
    AND s.cia = v.cia 
    AND s.alm = v.alm 
    AND s.sub_alm = v.cve 
    AND i.art = s.cve_art
    AND a.cia = s.cia 
    AND a.alm = s.alm 
    AND a.art = i.art
```

But, when I run both queries, I get different results. What can be wrong?

Comment: my mistake
 select distinct i.art, i.des1, isnull(l.porc_tol,0) as porc_tol, 0.0, a.cia, a.alm, i.art, i.lin,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only table that will potentially "produce" null values is table `l` which participates in an outer join with several other tables. In your version you also use the comma separator in the `from` clause, and have join conditions in the `where` clause. This is really mixing syntax from both worlds. This can be confusing for determining which is the scope of an outer join.

I would suggest this "translation" where all but the last table are all inner joined, to then use an outer join for including the last table in the query:

```
select distinct 
           i.art, i.des1, isnull(l.porc_tol,0) as porc_tol, 0.0, a.cia, 
           a.alm, i.art, i.lin, i.s_lin, i.fam, i.s_fam, i.marca, a.cve_pro 
from       invsas v (nolock)
inner join invars s (nolock) 
        on s.cia = v.cia 
       and s.alm = v.alm 
       and s.sub_alm = v.cve
inner join inviar i (nolock)
        on i.art = s.cve_art
inner join invart a (nolock)
        on a.cia = s.cia 
       and a.alm = s.alm 
       and a.art = i.art
left join  invtol l (nolock)
        on l.cia = s.cia 
       and l.suc = v.cve_suc 
       and l.cve_art = i.art  
where      v.cia = 'DEM' 
       and v.cve_suc ='001'
```